# How to use the 1st step in Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I'm confused on when to use the 1st step in CNF conversion.

1st Step: `ensure s does not appear on rhs, add new S0 if necessary and copy all rules of S`

It is not clear to me what the above statement means. I dont know when to create S0. Some CFG doesnt start with S0 and some starts with S0.

A little help here bros.

Answer (score 1):

The point is to avoid having the start symbol appear on the rhs i.e. as the result of a production. Therefore, you create a distinct symbol that becomes the one and only start symbol.

What are some of the examples of CFG that seem incorrect to you? They may not start with so, but the symbol they do start with should not appear as the result of a production.

Comment: he used S0 here:
`S->ASA|aB
 A->B|S
 B->b|e`
where e is epsilon.
But doesnt use S0 here:
`S->ab
 S->aSb`
S is on the rhs. I dont understand.

Comment: Neither of those is in cfg, and neither has S0. Are these the grammars you are going to reduce?

Comment: these are the grammars that were given as examples.

Comment: @yologaming my connections not good, and my edits aren't getting through. basically, your examples aren't cfg. The second one might look like S0 -> S, S -> ab | aS2, S2-> Sb however  if you are writing it in chomsky *reduced* form, s0 can be ommitted

Comment: thanks. i also learned that there will be no effect in the rules whether u create S0 or not. It just gives a distinct start symbol.